# Can we improve the current way spoilers are written?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, spoilers

I've noticed that when hovering over a question/answer with spoilers, the text displayed will instantly pop up, and will give no warning of "spoilers" until you hover over it.

Can we implement a feature that requires the user to either click on the box to show spoilers?  Or in other ways, show a warning (similar to how Steam shows Spoilerized screenshots) before users click on it?

Based on Robotnik's suggestions, I believe we could setup the spoiler tag this way:

**Before clicking on spoilers box:**

```
                 Possible spoilers, click to read at your own risk
```

**After clicking on spoilers box:**

```
In the end of Generic Game X, Y dies, and you resort to doing Z. Then Θ happens.
```

Comment: As a side note, the spoilers currently look like the user has left a lot of white space. There is no indication that when you hover your mouse over the white space you will see a spoiler (unless the poster kindly emphasized that). I think it would be a good idea if there was a button you had to actively click on to show the spoiler content.

Comment: That's an incredibly fair point.   Other sites distinguish it by adding a slightly beige tone to indicate certain spoilers, like this question: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/what-happens-to-the-members-of-w-i-s-e-near-the-end-of-the-psyren

Comment: Spoiler boxes are a light grey for me.

Comment: That's true, but it won't indicate there's a "spoiler" beneath it.  Having a spoiler text on the grey box when not hovering over it would help people avoid spoilers.

Comment: @Kexlox on my particular screen I do not see any difference between spoiler and whitespace. There should be a fairly large contrast ratio for people in low lighting situations.

Comment: -1 I like the system the way it is now.

Comment: Then why is everyone complaining about seeing spoilers? People are seeing spoilers inadvertently from email notifications, the super drop down collider, the hot questions page, etc.

Comment: @Retrosaur Right, people aren't complaining about how the spoilers appear in the question itself, they are complaining that the spoiler tag does not hide the text in all the places you list.

Comment: But at least a notifaction of "possible spoilers, read at your own caution" sort of thing, similar to how Steam Community does it

Comment: Are spoilers unique to arqade, or should this question be posted on the stackoverflow meta?

Comment: Should be unique to Gaming.SE, SciFi.SE, and Anime.SE, the three of which I believe this applies to the best.  I can't really see how SO could use this though...

Comment: MSO is not just the meta for StackOverflow.  It is used to discuss network-wide topics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update (Oct 2020):** Spoilers are now click-to-view, with a prompt on the right-hand side to 'reveal spoiler':

> Tada!

---

I personally believe you should have to click to view spoilers, as using a tiny touch-pad I sometimes accidentally mouse-over spoiler areas. This would be an area where having text as you suggested would be a good idea, saying something like "*Click to view this spoiler"*

Apart from that, perhaps we could make the spoiler area's colour darker, if it isn't showing up on people's screens? (as the comments on this question would suggest). I don't have a problem with the current colour. (but please comment if you can't see it).

Comment: Depending on the tilt of my laptop screen, it can be pretty difficult to see them at times. Even the beige spoilers on other sites are hard to notice aside from the small yellow bar on the side..